# Why apache with mod_wsgi timed out?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I was using apache with mod_wsgi to deploy my django project. What I did was:

1. `python manage.py startproject mysite` as the django tutorial guides,
2. add to apache conf/httpd.conf the following configuration:

   ```
   ServerName www.example.com
   ServerAlias example.com
   ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

   WSGIDaemonProcess example.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/root/mysite python-home=/usr
   WSGIProcessGroup example.com

   WSGIScriptAlias / /root/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

   <Directory /root/mysite/mysite>
   Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
3. type example.com in the address bar, then get time out response:

   Gateway Timeout

   The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.

How to handle this time-out in case of just a toy django app? I think it's not related to performance issues, but might be caused by some misconfiguration. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need:

```
python-home=/usr
```

as you are using the system Python. You only need that if using a Python virtual environment.

Now add:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

and see if that changes anything. It shouldn't if this is a brand new Django project, but if you have changed it and are importing certain Python packages that don't work in Python sub interpreters, you will need that.

Also check the Apache error log as it will give you a more precise reason as to why the timeout occurred.

---

UPDATE 1

If you compiled mod_wsgi yourself and want it to use `/usr/local/python3` for the Python installation, you will need to add:

```
WSGIPythonHome /usr/local/python3
```

just after the `LoadModule` line for `wsgi_module`. This is very important if you also have a system Python installation for version 3.6.

You also need to check whether it is picking up the correct shared library. Use `ldd` as explained in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library

to see what Python shared library it is picking up and whether it is find that under `/usr/local/python3/lib` or not. If it is picking up one from `/usr/lib` that will cause issues.

Comment: Hi, Graham. For formatting and content-limit reasons, I replied in another place.